# ChrW and AscW equivalent in Java (with Android SDK)

Tags: java, android, equivalent

I need the function that return the Ascii code (actually Unicode number code), as well as convert that code to the Unicode character one. They are ChrW and AscW in .NET. Ex: AscW("A") is 65, ChrW(65) is A.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, those are from VB.NET, not actually the .NET Framework.

In Java a `char` is *sort of* a integral type. You can convert it to `int` and back:

```
String s = "abc";
char a = s.charAt(0);
int a_codepoint = (int)a;

char x = (char)120;
```

Comment: Similarly, if you're just wanting a function you could also do `Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0))` as an equivalent to AscW. Although, there doesn't appear to be a similar function in Integer.  This method is probably slower (and a lot more wordy) than a simple cast, though

Comment: All strings and characters in Java use Unicode. UTF-16, to be precise. So technically a `char` is an UTF-16 *code unit* and not a code point.